# Sending http request to servers anonymously

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, axios

I'm just wondering if we could send HTTP request to API / Web Server anonymously? right now after some googling. i cannot find any answer if it is possible.

i'm writing a code that will scrape the data from its server but i think they might have an API monitoring feature for their Data.

right now i am using node with Axios and the script i am using is fetching almost ~10k requests per minute, which i think is bad because their server could blew up.

i tried googling but i didn't find any answer to my problem.

Comment: I've been on the receiving end (so to speak) of out-of-control scrapers more than once in my career, so all I'll be offering is some advice: perhaps you could contact the owner of the website and come to some sort of agreement regarding the use of their data? In a lot of countries, scraping websites is at best a grey legal area, and sometimes downright forbidden (especially if it causes outages, i.e. monetary damages).

Comment: "10k requests per minute" yes it's bad, really bad.

Comment: so perhaps i should make an interval every request just like their website do every time you clicked link.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Sending http request to servers anonymously

The HTTP protocol uses TCP as the underlying transport protocol. The TCP protocol uses the three-way handshake to establish connections. In theory you could send packets without your source address, or with someone else's address - just like you could write someone else's address as a sender on an envelope in traditional mail.

Now, the three-way handshake works like this: You send the first SYN packet, then the server sends a SYN-ACK packet - to whom? If your address was not in the first SYN packet then the server cannot send you the second packet. And if you cannot get the SYN-ACK packet then you cannot even establish the connection. This is all before you can even think about sending the HTTP request on the TCP connection because there is no connection.

So, the answer is: No. You cannot send HTTP requests anonymously because you cannot establish a TCP connection anonymously.

Of course you could use a proxy, VPN, a tunnel, NAT or something like that so that the requests appear as not originating from you but keep in mind that the proxy needs to know your address to pass responses to you so you are not completely anonymous, just someone else knows who you are and that someone else will not hesitate to reveal your identity as soon as you cause any trouble.

Comment: thank you!

perhaps i should make an interval every http request to their server to simulate their website. 

i was just wondering when you send http request using cURL, javascript. php or anything. server side or client side. 

what address do these used?